# MSDTC error on different databases, same server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, msdtc, escalation

I'm currently trying to correct this error:

System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.

Happening at one of our UAT environments. The thing is we have on server A two UAT environments, let's call them UAT1 and UAT2, both of them pointing to the same SQL Server at Server B, different databases. On Server B MSDTC is NOT running.

(BTW, enabling MSDTC does not work: the error persists)

And the MSDTC error only happens on UAT2 when performing a certain operation in our website. Doing the same operation on UAT1 does NOT raise the error, although they have the same configuration, website code, they both point to the same SQL server and the different databases in that SQL Server have the same configuration, I've checked thrice. I've read that using different connection strings inside the same transaction will escalate the transaction to DTC, and we have slightly different connection strings for "normal" DB operations and logging DB operations; BUT both environments have the same connection strings and again, one raises the error and the other doesn't. I don't know where else to look and my question is: am I missing something? Is there a place, configuration, registry entry, logfile or whatever I can check to see what's the difference?

Thanks to all and sorry for the vagueness.